# Нумерация элементов в smarty

Tags: php, html, smarty

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, как мне пронумеровать в smarty(v2) класс каждой

в зависимости от количества элементов ?

```
<ul>
   <li class="1">
   <li class="2">
   <li class="3">
   <li class="4">
<ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ul>
{foreach from=$myArray key=k item=v}
   <li class="{$k}">: {$v}</li>
{/foreach}
</ul>
```

Comment: что, очевидно, не будет работать в случае ассоциативного массива

Comment: @teran, полностью согласен.

Answer (score 0):

циклы `foreach` в `smarty` имеют свойства `index` и `iteration`, первое из которых определяет индекс элемента массива, начиная с нуля. Второе - счетчик итераций, начиная с 1.
Для использования свойств в [smarty-2](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/ru/language.function.foreach.tpl) необходимо поименовать цикл с использованием атрибута `name`.
Таким образом, вывод номеров элементов цикла (вне зависимости от формы массива) будет иметь следующий вид:

```
<ul>
{foreach from=$items item=i name=foo}
    <li class="{$smarty.foreach.foo.iteration}">{$i}</li>
{/foreach} 
</ul>
```

В [Smarty-3](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.foreach.tpl) все куда удобнее:

```
<ul>
{foreach $items as $i}
    <li class="{$i@iteration}">{$i}</li>
{/foreach} 
</ul>
```